# Improving Bellman-Ford to Linear Run Time

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science, graph-algorithm

In the Johnson algorithm, it uses Bellman-Ford to convert graphs with negative edge weights(no negative cycles) into a graph with the same shortest paths but all the edge weights being non-negative - in O(mn) time.

Suppose we are given a DAG. How could we use an alternative method to convert the DAG into another graph with the same shortest paths, however in linear time as opposed to the previous O(mn) time.

I'm assuming we could modify Bellman-Ford during execution of the Johnson algorithm, however I'm unsure how to make it linear. Essentially, how could we figure out a way to reweight all edges in a graph to be non-negative in linear O(n) time?

Comment: For a dag there is another algorithm you can use which runs in O(n + m): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-for-directed-acyclic-graphs/

Comment: Would we still use this in combination with Johnsons algorithm? e.g. replace the step in Johnsons algorithm that uses Bellman-Ford(O(mn)) with this algorithm instead O(n+m) as you mentioned?

Comment: I believe you can run the algorithm for all vertices, thus getting shortest path between all vertices in O(n (n + m)) complexity. Here are more details: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169575&seqNum=5